# WooCommerce get All variation by product

Tags: wordpress, api, woocommerce, vuejs3

Hi I use the API of WooCommerce and I want to retrieve all the variations of a product which are 50 in number
but I recover from the first 10 elements with axios
how to recover all the variations.

```
         getVariationPrice : function () {
            let url = "products/4227/variations?per_page=50&
          consumer_key="+this.ck+"&consumer_secret="+this.cs
           axios.get(this.BaseUrl + url)
            .then((response) => {
                this.variations = response.data
                console.log(this.variations, );
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.error(error);
            })
       }
```

Comment: `['per_page' => 100]` - check the page parameter. By default it's 10

Comment: to get ALL use
 'per_page' => -1

Comment: Hi @mujuonly in the response there is no such parameter and I see nowhere in the documentation where it is mentioned 
maybe I didn't see it too well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

per_page=50 parameter will surely provide the desired variations.
http://example.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products/12/variations?per_page=50

Here is the official documentation statement: Requests that return multiple items will be paginated to 10 items by default.
https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#pagination

Comment: it still doesn't work when I try the pagination with the per_page parameter I get a 400 bad request error

Comment: I checked http://example.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products/12/variations?per_page=50 is giving me more than 10 variations. Error 400 is a client error that occurs due to incorrect requests, invalid syntax, or routing issues. Can you please check/share your request format that is hitting to WooCommerce API endpoints?

Comment: Hi biplob I update my question now you can check my request in the API

Comment: Can you please check the request in postman first? Here is the screenshot of my request format where per_page parameter is working fine https://prnt.sc/ZYN-64kxsktO

Comment: Thank you very much I just reviewed this project and it works